# LitElement with Typescript, cannot access shadowRoot doms

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom, lit-element

My query selector or getElementById always returns null, can someone explain to me why? tried everything I can think off (and found on the internet) but nothing works.

```
@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {

@property({type : String}) carousel = document.querySelectorAll("[data-target='carousel']");

connectedCallback(): void {
    super.connectedCallback();

    console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slider'));
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.slider'));
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#slider'));
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.getElementById('slider'));

    console.log(document.getElementById('slider'));

}

render(){
    return html`
        <div class="slider" id="slider">
            <ul class="carousel" data-target="carousel">
```

Comment: Does your component display properly? Can you post the rest of the component code?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). `document.getElementById('slider')` doesn't work because the element isn't a member of `document`'s light DOM; it's a member of `my-element`s shadow DOM, which is also the reason `this.shadowRoot.getElementById('slider')` *does* work. This is by design. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need a reference to that element outside of MyElement?

Answer (score 3):

Please try with the following:

```
@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {

  get root() {
    return this.shadowRoot || this
  }

   render(){
    return html`<div class="slider" id="slider">...`
   }

   firstUpdated() {
    console.log(this.root.getElementById('slider')
   }
}
```